# Installed Ubuntu via Wubi, upgraded, now my network card appears to be fried

Tags: networking, windows

Okay, so here's what's been going on:

I installed Ubuntu via Wubi yesterday, worked fine. Installed Gnome shell, etc, etc. I was on it today, noticed there were a tonne of updates to install, which I did. Then, I logged back onto my Windows, played some tf2. Next, I decided to get Microsoft Office working on Ubuntu, only to notice there was no internet. Logged onto Windows, same thing.

I've been trying to get it to work for 5 hours. Completely uninstalled Ubuntu, re-installed Network Card drivers, nothing. I've done everything I can think of, short of reinstalling Windows.

When I plug my ethernet cable in, the lights that usually go on around the socket simply don't light up, so I'm wondering if somehow my network card broke during the updates that installed on Ubuntu.

Any ideas? Sorry if this isnt the right place to post it, but I'm kinda desperate, and fairly sure it happened because of Ubuntu.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't at all know what could have possibly happened, but here's something you can try to confirm the network card has failed: Make a liveCD/liveUSB and boot into Ubuntu with it on your machine. If, from the liveCD, you can use wireless, something probably went wrong within Windows and somehow affected the wubi installation.

If, within the live environment, wireless still fails to work, I can only suggest taking the machine to hardware folks.

Comment: Ooh, never thought of that, yeah I'll definitely give it a go!